# Автотесты на Java Selenium. Среда разработки для отладки кода в режиме реального времени

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

Начинаю осваивать написание автотестов на Java, интересует следующий вопрос: есть ли простая и удобная среда для отладки автотестов в режиме реального времени?
Что имею в виду: когда писал автотесты на Python использовал Python IDLE для, например, проверки кликов и ожиданий, то есть в режиме реального времени я отправлял команду и видел результат в браузере, без ожидания компиляции программы. Сейчас работая в IntelliJ IDEA столкнулся с проблемой: часто получаю NPE из-за того, что драйвер не находит элемент, но уже во время выполнения автотеста.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В IntelliJ IDEA есть возможность, которая близка по удобству  к консоли питона (или даже более удобна). Речь идет о расширенном режиме вычисления выражений.

Ставим точку останова или доходим до нужного места пошагово. Далее открываем `Evaluate Expression ...`, а потом нажимаем на `Expand (Shift+Enter)`:

[image: Expand expression]

После этого можно выполнять многократно любые куски кода в текущем контексте, включая определение переменных. Автодополнение работает без проблем:

[image: Code fragment evaluation]

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь полегче будет