# Как возобновить работу кода с нужной строки

Tags: python, selenium

В моем python selenium проекте довольно много различной логики, работа одной итерации цикла длится около 15 минут и я иногда получаю исключения или неверную работу скрипта, это приводит к остановке всей работы программы. Возможно ли выполнить правки в коде и запустить повторно например с N строки и продолжить работу?

Спасибо!

Comment: Зациклить то место, что падает. Если код выполнился, то выйти из цикла

Answer (score 3):

На ходу менять код питон программы, которая уже загружена и выполняется, просто не получится. Но можно сделать то, что вам нужно, чуть другим способом. Далее я предполагаю, что тест запускаете из консоли. Из IDE можно делать аналогично, принцип тот же что описан ниже, но отличаются технические детали (как ставить точки останова, как вызывать фукнции вручную и т.д. см. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155186/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java-selenium-%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be/1155224#1155224)).

По сути хочется отладить кусок программы, на ходу делая изменения. Допустим кусок выглядит так:

```
f1()
f2()
f3()
f4()
```

где `f1`-`f4` это вызовы либо ваших функций, либо библиотечных.

Первое, что нужно это получить управление в отладчике. Либо просто поставить точку останова в начале или завернуть это все в `try-except` и поставить точку останова в `except`. Допустим, выбран второй вариант:

```
try:
  f1()
  f2()
  f3()
  f4()
except Exception as e:
  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Теперь, когда случается исключение в блоке, вы попадаете в отладчик. Находясь там, можно:

1. вручную делать любые действия в браузере
2. выполнять команды, вызывать функции и свои и библиотечные так, как бы они выполнялись в программе
3. установить новые точки останова в отладчике
4. продолжить выполнение программы с любой строки в текущем фрейме стека

Я обычно использую шаг 2 для того, чтобы интерактивно создавать нужные шаги в программе и переношу их в редактор (чтобы при следующем запуске с самого начала они уже выполнились как готовая часть программы).

Точки останова задаются командой [break](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break). Продолжить выполнение с заданой строки можно командой [jump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-jump).

Допустим в нашем примере `f1` выполнилась успешно, а в процессе выполнения `f2` бросилось исключение. Тогда можно вручную вернуть состояние в браузере до момента перед выполнением `f2`. Если сбой в `f2` вызван ошибкой в `f2`, то выполняем вручную модифицированные команды из `f2` (при этом сохраняя их в редакторе). При ручном выполнении команды selenium типа `нажать на кнопку` и т.п. будут выполнятся точно также как бы они выполнялись в обычно запуске. После того как `f2` таким образом пройдена вручную, можно давать команду `jump <номер_строки_f3()>`.

Так же для удобства рекомендую вместо встроенного `pdb` использовать [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/).

Если есть вопросы по подходу, пишите - дополню ответ.