# Как правильно задать webdriver

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

пишу парсер для сайте Rozetka.com, все компилирует без ошибок, но почему-то ничего в таблицу не выводит, видимо ошибка в том как я указал пусть к webdriver, подскажите как это сделать

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd
import time
webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe" ### put your browser driver's path

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer") ### here the website url

items = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted")) ### here you put the class name of the HTML element which contains the data to scrap

total = []
for item in range(items):

        items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted")
        for item in items:
            t_name = item.find_element_by_class_name('goods-tile__title').text
            t_price = item.find_element_by_class_name('goods-tile__price-value').text
            t_nal = item.find_element_by_class_name('goods-tile__availability goods-tile__availability--available ng-star-inserted').text
            new = ((cur_data,t_name, t_price, t_nal))
            total.append(new)
            cur_data = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['time','Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv('Rozetka_parcer_{cur_data}.csv')
driver.close()
```

Comment: Компилируется или все-таки интерпретируется? О_о Не вижу связи между путем к webdriver для работы selenium и сохранением в таблицу, если бы путь был неправильный, то скрипт дальше `driver = Chrome(webdriver)` не пошел. Скорее всего, у вас в `total` ничего нет, добавляйте отладочные сообщения и смотрите в консоли как код выполняется

Comment: Если бы ошибка была в пути к драйверу, то выскочило бы исключение.

Comment: Кст, а зачем два раза запрашивать `goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted` и делать двойной цикл с ними? Выглядит странно... мне кажется, что код с `items = len(...` и `for item in range(items):` лишний

Comment: Ну смотрите, я вытягиваю данные и заношу их в csv, все вроде бы работает нормально, компиляция проходит, запускается окно с браузером, но потом все обрывается и никаких данных нет

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1267411/218971 Я там описывал, как вести отладку selenium тестов. Попробуйте пошагово в отладчике выполнить тест и посмотрите, где работает не так, как должно (как вы ожидаете)

Comment: самый первый ход, который должен быть: вставить print(items) и посмотреть, есть ли там вообще хоть что-нибудь. Потому что если там 0, то ничего и не будет дальше происходить

Comment: А если 0, то получается проблема в классах?

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, ага. Мб их еще нет, т.к. сайт теги с ними подгружает, мб вы ошиблись в использовании метода `find_elements_by_class_name`. Добавлю ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, у вас не нашлось из-за неправильного использования метода [find_elements_by_class_name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name), которому нужно передавать один класс. Поясню, значения в атрибуте `class`, разделенные пробелом, это не один элемент (`class`), а несколько.

Таким образом, значение `goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted` это 2 класса

Для поиска по двум классам используйте css-селектор через метод [find_elements_by_css_selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-tile__picture.ng-star-inserted")
```