# Не получаю данные из парсера

Tags: python, selenium

Написал парсер с помощью Selenium, но после цикла проверки возвращает только "0", что я сделал не так?

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd
import time
webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe" ### put your browser driver's path

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer") ### here the website url

items = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted")) ### here you put the class name of the HTML element which contains the data to scrap

total = []
for item in range(items):

        items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted")
        for item in items:
            itemName = item.find('span', class_='goods-tile__title').text.strip()
            itemPrice = item.find('span', class_='goods-tile__price-value').text
            itemNal = item.find('div', class_='goods-tile__availability goods-tile__availability--available ng-star-inserted').text.strip()
            new = ((cur_data,itemName, itemPrice, itemNal))
            total.append(new)
            cur_data = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['time','Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv('Rozetka_parcer_{cur_data}.csv')
print(items)
driver.close()
```

Еще пробовал вот такой вариант:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd
import time
import request 
webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe" ### put your browser driver's path

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer") ### here the website url

items = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted")) ### here you put the class name of the HTML element which contains the data to scrap

total = []
for item in range(items):

        items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted")
        for item in items:
            t_name = item.find_element_by_class_name('goods-tile__title').text
            t_price = item.find_element_by_class_name('ng-star-inserted').text
            t_nal = item.find_element_by_class_name('goods-tile__availability goods-tile__availability--available ng-star-inserted').text
            new = ((cur_data,t_name, t_price, t_nal))
            total.append(new)
            cur_data = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['time','Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv('Rozetka_parcer_{cur_data}.csv')
print(items)
driver.close()
```

Не думаю, что проблема в webdriver, потому что при компиляции к нему вопросов нет, открывает окно и заходит на нужный сайт, а вот данные не вытягивает.

Comment: значит нет таких данных

Comment: и вопрос для размышлений: если код найдет 10 элементов, удовлетворяющих условию, то сколько раз будет парситься страница?

Comment: А как тогда ввести классы что бы оно обнаружило данные? Все классы перепробовал и не получается

Comment: По-мне так, этот вопрос дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1337512/201445